vercel/postgres await sql `` - how to pass revalidation/caching configs in?
It looks like my app is fetching old data. I have dropped the table and recreated a new one (added a new column) and reseeded it with new data. But when running the app it still returns the old data, and the new column is undefined - it appears the server somehow cached the old data somewhere.
I didn't find good documentation around passing revalidation configs via the sql method of vercel/postgres, does anyone know?

There isn't enough context in your question. Please improve it to contain a code example so we can narrow it down to a possible answer.
